# Sequalize.js :TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined\n at Instance.set in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, mean

I have a Field name as "Model" in MSSQl. Am unable to use the field name as "Model" in attributes. Kindly help to find the solution to use "Model" db field in attributes.

Following is my code:

```
import * as  Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { Config } from '../config/config';
const sequelize = Config.SequelizeConnection;
export class References {
public getAllProjects(tableName: string) {
    return sequelize.define(tableName, {
        Model   : {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }
   })
   };

 }

public getAllProjects(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

     let references = new References ();
    let projects = references.getAllProjects('test');
    let db = new SequelizeHelper();
    projects.findAll().then(projects => {
            return Api.ok(req, res, projects);
        }, (err) => {
            next(err);
        });
```

Getting this error:
"Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined",........